# Easy data storage formats for c++ begginners

Tags: c++

I'm making a c++ program and need a way to store data for users and things like that. I've tried JSON, but the libraries are very difficult to use, at least for a beginner like me. I am looking for a key-value pair type format. JSON work, if I could find an easier library for that.

Comment: You can save it in a fale using `freopen` or `ofstream`.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to save? What did you try with json that didn't work?

Comment: You're right, this is way too vague and you need to research your options more before asking.  When you say _"nothing I do seems to work"_, you must _qualify_ that statement by showing what you did and explaining how it did not "work".  Then someone might be able to help.  Beyond this, think about your actual requirements.  For example: Do you need super-fast storage and/or retrieval?  Do you need indexing for searches?  Do you need to run this in highly parallel environments?  Do you need robustness and data integrity guarantees?  Do you just need simplicity?  The list goes on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for storage formats for data, then options are -

1. XML (3rd party libraries available)
2. JSON (3rd party libraries available)
3. INI file (key value pair in text file)
4. CSV format (text file)
5. Object serialization
   etc

Storage mechanisms are -

1. File store (XML, JSON, CSV as plain text file)
2. Database (RDBMS, Object store)
3. In memory objects

Above are few regularly used storage techniques in C++ (and many other languages also).

~Nilesh